# jQuery in Wordpress. Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Trying to load a calculator widget for interest rates.

Unfortunately I'm getting an Uncaught type error, with this script:

```
$('.hire-purchase.calculator-widget').each(function() { 
 var app = new LHV.HirePurchase(); 
 app.init($(this)); 
 });
```

It is working fine, when I load the widget in a separate .html file with all the necessary script and jQuery. Although when I add it to the webpage in development it conflicts. What could be the problem?

Comment: At first glance, are 'LHV' and 'app' are defined?

Comment: I'm using this script for LHV:
http://tinyurl.com/mv4bqza

and jquery.

The calculator works perfect in a seperate file

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved. Wordpress didn't fancy $, changed it to jQuery in the jquery activation and the LHV script also.